# Модальное окно не блокирует доступ к родительскому

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть два окна, родительское и модальное с авторизацией (допустим).
В родительском код:

```
Window1 CLWindow = new Window1();
CLWindow.ShowDialog();
```

На просторах инэта сказано, что так создается модальное окно, однако я все равно могу использовать кнопки в родительском, как исправить?

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Создайте пустой проект с двумя окнами и проверьте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй указать `Owner`-а:

```
Window1 CLWindow = new Window1();
CLWindow.Owner = this;
CLWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Если его поставить перед ***CLWindow.ShowDialog();***, то ошибка **System.InvalidOperationException: "Невозможно задать в свойстве Owner объект Window, который не был показан ранее."**, а если  после, то тоже не работает, а при закрытие модального окна вручную вываливается ошибка: **Нельзя применить к закрытому окну**

Comment: Как вариант просто перед этим блочить элементы управления вручную, но это долго...

Comment: @SKProCH, покажите, где вы вызываете новое окно.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gq6mf1

Comment: @SKProCH, покажите весь код, я имел ввиду.